# using react: TypeError: value.products.map is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am working on react e-commerce site with products etc.  I am getting the above error and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Below is the productlist page:

(Code)

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import Product from "./Product";
    import Title from './Title';
    import {ProductConsumer} from '../context';

    export default class ProductList extends Component{
    render() {               
        return(
        <React.Fragment>
        <div className="py-5">
        <div className="container">
        <Title name="our" title="products"/>

       <div className="row"> 
      <ProductConsumer>
     {value=>{
      return value.products.map( product =>{           #here is where the error is.
        return <Product key={product.id} product={product}/>;
      });
      }}              
    </ProductConsumer>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        </React.Fragment>
       // <Product/>
    );
   }      
   }
```

*end of code

Hope someone can put me in the right direction. Thanks, Jen

Answer (score 0):

I can guess that value.products could be an object, instead of an array.
could be an object containing the array of products, to be more sure, Can you share the code for ProductConsumer ?

it would also be quite helpful to put a  **console.log(value)** before that line

```
<ProductConsumer>
    {value=>{
        console.log('Product Value:',value) // --- post the output of that line
        return value.products.map( product =>{ 
         return <Product key={product.id} product={product}/>;
        });
    }}              
</ProductConsumer>
```

Also, a side hint,
**<React.Fragment>  </React.Fragment>** can be replaced as **<> </>**

Answer (score 0):

You can Try

```
<ProductConsumer>
     {value &&
        value?.products.map((product) => {
          return <Product key={product.id} product={product} />;
        })}
</ProductConsumer>
```